# Firebase Functions internal error when calling emulator function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo

I am trying to connect my Expo project with Firebase Function's local emulator, but I keep getting an `internal` error whenever I try to call a function.

Here is my `firebase.js` file on the front end:

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/functions";
import {
  FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
} from "@env";

// initialize firebase config
const config = {
  apiKey: FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator("http://localhost:5001");

export { firebase };
```

Here's my `firebase.json` file on back-end:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas what this might be, or how I may be able to read into the error a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up updating firebase functions using the command below in my `functions/` directory

```
npm install firebase-functions
```